# Definition of a Picard Group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth variety. Then we know that the picard group of $X$ is the quotient $\text{Div}(X)/\text{Princ}(X)$ of the group of divisors of $X$ by the subgroup of principal divisors of $X$.

Now suppose in the case where $X$ is a complex manifold,  one has the exponential sequence: $$ 0\mapsto 2\pi i \mathbb{Z} \mapsto \mathcal{O}_X \mapsto \mathcal{O}_X^\ast \mapsto 0$$

Now we know from usual cohomology that one has the induced morphiam $$H^1(X, \mathcal{O}_X^\ast) \mapsto H^2(X, \mathbb{Z})$$ I've also read that in this case $H^1(X, ,\mathcal{O}_X^\ast)$ is the Picard Group of $X$ as well.

My question is how are the two definitions of the Picard Group I've stated above equivalent? Moreover, how does is image of morphism identified as the Neron-Severi group of $X$? The usual definition I have for the Neron-Severi group is the group of Cartier divisors modulo numerical equivalence.  Would be thankful if anyone can provide some answers.

Comment: You may wish to consult Hartshorne exercise III.4.5, which leads you through a proof $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X^\ast)\cong Pic(X)$ for any ringed space $X$. I think there might be more going on with the text you cite - the given map into $H^2$ you describe need not be injective, which would only give you a quotient of the Picard group rather than the whole thing.

Comment: @KReiser Oh my bad. It is the Neron-Severi group* not the Picard Group! I have edited the question. Sorry about it.

Comment: You can use the following exact sequence : 
$$0\to \mathcal{O}_X^*\to \mathcal{K}_X^*\to \mathcal{K}_X^*/\mathcal{O}_X^*\to 0$$ where $\mathcal{K}_X^*$ is the sheaf of rational functions. This induces $H^0(X, \mathcal{K}_X^*/\mathcal{O}_X^*)\to H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X^*)$ which is onto under some very general hypotheses. Almost by definition, $H^0(X, \mathcal{K}_X^*/\mathcal{O}_X^*)=\operatorname{Div}(X)$ and the image of $H^0(X, \mathcal{K}_X^*)$ is $\operatorname{Princ}(X)$. Hence the isomorphism $\operatorname{Div}(X)/\operatorname{Princ}(X)=H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X^*)$.

Comment: @Roland Thank you very much for the response. I would like to clarify the following: The definition of $\text{Div}(X)$ I know is the (collection of) formal sums of prime divisors over $X$. However I interpret $H^0(X, \mathcal{K}_X^\ast/\mathcal{O}_X^\ast)$ as the global section of $X$, i.e. all regular functions $f$ vanishing at some point. How are these two equal by definition?

Comment: Ok I was using the notion of Cartier divisor and you are using the notion of Weil divisor. There is always a map $\operatorname{CaDiv}(X)\to\operatorname{Div}(X)$. On a smooth scheme this map is an isomorphism.

Comment: @Roland yes this explains it! Thank you so much